# Terraform: AWS Inspector plan fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform to manage AWS infrastructure. I am completely new to AWS and terraform and the information is overwhelming.

I am trying to enable the service AWS Inspector though terraform using the following code:

```
resource "aws_inspector_assessment_template" "example" {
  name       = "example"
#   target_arn = aws_inspector_assessment_target.example.arn
  duration   = 3600

#   rules_package_arns = [
#     "arn:aws:inspector:us-west-2:758058086616:rulespackage/0-9hgA516p",
#     "arn:aws:inspector:us-west-2:758058086616:rulespackage/0-H5hpSawc",
#     "arn:aws:inspector:us-west-2:758058086616:rulespackage/0-JJOtZiqQ",
#     "arn:aws:inspector:us-west-2:758058086616:rulespackage/0-vg5GGHSD",
#   ]
}
```

But all I am getting is the following error:

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on aws_inspector.tf line 1, in resource "aws_inspector_assessment_template" "example":
   1: resource "aws_inspector_assessment_template" "example" {

The argument "rules_package_arns" is required, but no definition was found.


Error: Missing required argument

  on aws_inspector.tf line 1, in resource "aws_inspector_assessment_template" "example":
   1: resource "aws_inspector_assessment_template" "example" {

The argument "target_arn" is required, but no definition was found.
```

This is obviously because I commented out `target_arn` and `rules_package_arns`.

The thing is I don't understand what these variables are and what values to give the. Could you please help me figure this out?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/inspector_rules_packages uses them all together, maybe that helps.

Comment: How did it go? Does the issue still persist? Did you create missing resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **shouldn't comment out** all the required parts. Thus your error.

You also have to create [aws_inspector_assessment_target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/inspector_assessment_target), and can use [aws_inspector_rules_packages](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/inspector_rules_packages) to get the ARNs that you require. Having these resources you can reference them in your `aws_inspector_assessment_template`.

An example is [TF docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/inspector_rules_packages#example-usage):

```
# Declare the data source
data "aws_inspector_rules_packages" "rules" {}

# e.g. Use in aws_inspector_assessment_template
resource "aws_inspector_resource_group" "group" {
  tags = {
    test = "test"
  }
}

resource "aws_inspector_assessment_target" "assessment" {
  name               = "test"
  resource_group_arn = aws_inspector_resource_group.group.arn
}

resource "aws_inspector_assessment_template" "assessment" {
  name       = "Test"
  target_arn = aws_inspector_assessment_target.assessment.arn
  duration   = "60"

  rules_package_arns = data.aws_inspector_rules_packages.rules.arns
}
```